# CKEditor - Can I lock text in place or make the doc another size?

Tags: text, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in a web app I'm creating which prints a lot of documents. Letters, labels...

Does anybody know how to lock text in place? I want to be able to lock certain pieces of text at the bottom of the page (A4) but when I write above this it can't move down it must stay locked. I'm using it on my web app which prints different sized documents and some parts of the documents mustn't move. (E.g. locked at the bottom of the doc and then when I add information to the doc which is always above the text I want locked it can't be pushed down.

I'm trying to set up a template doc so I can merge all info in later and not worry about the parts I need 'locked' moving everywhere.

Also, as mentioned before that I use different sized documents.. is there a way I can select these sizes or view them in a more structured way to the relevant size I want to print it in? The smallest is around 110mm by 140mm but the rest are A4. Or would this be another issue not to do with the document editor?

Please ask any questions if you need more info and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I am using CKEditor 4.5.4

Comment: I am printing a Cheque so I want to mail merge data at the bottom of the A4 page and I need it to stay exactly where I set it even when I write above it at the top of the A4 sheet (Letter with cheque at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

You can set contenteditable="false" to lock element from editing.

```
<p contenteditable="false">I can't edit this text</p>
```

To lock the position you can set the fixed or absolute

```
<p style="position:fixed; bottom:10px; left:10px;">I can't move this text</p>
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately this didn't work. The text did stay but I couldn't put it at the bottom no matter how much I tried. I try to put it down the bottom and it always ends up half way down the page when printing